# A way to compute and store the short url for a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Let's say you have simple model called `Project` and you need to store it's short url for later usage, when is the best way to compute it?

The best solution I have for now is a after_create hook, but that leads to code like

> short_url || Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.project_path(project, host: HOSTNAME)

It does not feel right to access the url from the model.

In short, where do you put the code to compute the short_url?

Thank you,

Comment: IMHO there is no problem to have a short url stored in database, you can use bitly gem (https://rubygems.org/gems/bitly) to generate these urls. Take a look at this example https://github.com/meurio/panela-de-pressao/blob/master/app/models/campaign.rb#L23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add this code in the controller.

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @project = Project.new(params[:project])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        @project.update_attribute(:short_url, project_url(@project))
        (..)
  end
end
```

It feels like this code belongs to the controller as it deals with http/url. Storing in the db sounds ok, but asking for the url is the controller's responsibility.

The line:

```
@project.update_attribute(:short_url, project_url(@project))
```

needs to be added below the call to .save (or .create), as only then the project_url helper can be called (the project object got its id already).

Comment: you are right, but what if you create projects from different places, let's say part of your registration project will create a new project for you also

Comment: In that case, I'd consider creating a CreateProjectService class, that would be called from both places. The new class would have probably take the controller or the helpers object as the parameter.

Comment: this sounds like a better approach, do you know any examples of this pattern for rails apps?

Comment: Here is a simple example: https://github.com/codeclimate/refactoring-fat-models/tree/master/2-service-objects It's also described in this blog post: http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you dont want to save the exact `short_url` instead?  So when you need the url for the project object, you can just check if the short_url is present or not.  I believe you can just add a decorator to determine the url of project.

```
#using Draper
class ProjectDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  def effective_url
    source.short_url.present? ? source.short_url : project_path(source)
    # or source.short_url || project_path(source) if short_url will not be an empty string
    # or source.short_url || source
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank your for your reply but my question is where do I put the code to compute the short url?

Comment: ah I thought your question was whether what you're currently doing is fine (since you're accessing the named route in your model).  I actually think that's fine but unnecessary since you can use a decorator to return the effective url of the project.